# Trying to compare a fully fixed and and fully random model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model

So I have a data set which I am modeling using the following:

`model1 <- lm(subject ~ .^2, data=hre.train)`

This model treats all of the variables as fixed.  I want to compare this model to a model which treats all variables as random. Would I use something like:

`model2<-lmer(subject~(1|town)+(1|district)+(1|street)+(1|family)+(1|gender)+(1|replicate),data=hre.train)`

I can construct a fully nested model by using

`model3<-lme(subject~1,random=~1|town/district/street/family/gender/replicate,data=hre.train)`

I just keep getting an error when I use

`anova(model1,model2,model3)`

The goal is to build an optimal mixed model for prediction but I need something to compare to when I start combining fixed and random effects (i.e gender as fixed, others as random etc)

Comment: Curious why you would model all of your effects as random? Are there no explicit comparisons of one level against another that you are interested in (fixed effect)?

Comment: No specific reason, I am just trying to learn about random vs mixed effects in linear models and thought that having a fully random model to compare specific effects to would be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are comparing models with different fixed effects you have to make sure you are using  ML method (method="ML" in R) vs. the default REML method. Maybe that is why you are having trouble using the ANOVA function?